# Get location from JavaScript and pass it to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I want to get the longitude and latitude using javascript, and than to compare it with the previous location. Something like Facebook does when you log in from another computer, but much more simplified. In order to achieve this I have created 2 hidden fields and when the user submits the form the values are to be sent to the server.

```
<body>
<p id="log">Login to continue:
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="user" required >
        Password: <input type="password" required>
    <input type="hidden" name= "longitude" id="longitude">
    <input type= "hidden" name ="latitude" id="latitude">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="getLocation()">
</p>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("log");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;  
     document.getElementByID("longitude").value = longitude;
     document.getElementByID("latitude").value = latitude;

  }

</script>
```

But in **welcome.php** the code :

```
$latitude=$_POST["latitude"];
$longtude=$_POST["longitude"];
```

returns :
 *Notice: Undefined index: **latitude** in C:\xampp\htdocs\welcome.php on line 8*

*Notice: Undefined index: **longitude** in C:\xampp\htdocs\welcome.php on line 9*

Is there better way to do this, and how to fix this?

Comment: You use getElementById but the fields do not have an ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access the elements by ID, but they have no ID.

Either add an ID attribute to them, or reference them in a different way.

Comment: I fix that , but still the same :/

Answer (score 1):

you have made mistake on `document.getElementByID` the d should be small ie `document.getElementById`

Comment: A combination of your and @Kolink's answer has to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
function showPosition(position)
  {
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;  
     document.getElementByID("longitude").value = longitude;
     document.getElementByID("latitude").value = latitude;

  }
```

to this

```
function showPosition(position)
  {
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;  
     document.getElementById("longitude").value = longitude;
     document.getElementById("latitude").value = latitude;

  }
```

And it should work

Answer (score 0):

Open firebug, click on label network and take a look into the post request if parameters langitude and longitude have been sent. If yes, the failure must be in your php script. If you cant't find both parameters, check your client code.